# using language C to read a file "txt"

Tags: c, eof

I create a table named "sequence" to registe the number in each router read for the text "structure.txt".nomber of router is "nb_input", nomber of path we can choose is "nb_output".

For example, if in the txt like this:**router1 1 3 4**,  it means sequence[0][0]=1,
sequence[0][2]=1,sequence[0][3]=1

My "structure.txt" is like this:

[image]

My code is like that. nb_input=6,nb_output=16 predefine before

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
#define WHITESPACE   0x20
#define TAB     0x09
int main()
{
    FILE    *fStruct, *fPara;
    char    line[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int     i = 0, j=0;
    char    parameters_name[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char    parameters_value[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int     nb_input;
    int     nb_output;
    int     sum_size;
    int     b;
    int     c;
    int     l=0;
    char    s[10];
    int     k=0;
    int     start=0;
    int     sequence[nb_input][nb_output];
        /*inisalisation of sequence array*/
        for (i=0;i<nb_input;i++)
        {
            for (j=0;j<nb_output;j++)
            {
                sequence[i][j]=0;
            }
        }
    fStruct = fopen("C:/Users/13383/Desktop/creater_noc/structure.txt","rt");
    if(fStruct == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR: Can't open file.");
        exit(1);
    }
    int r;
    while(fgets(line, BUFFER_SIZE, fStruct) != NULL) // Read a line
    {
       i = 0, j=0,l=0,start=0,c=0,b=0,k=0;
       memset(s, 0, sizeof(s));

        while(line[i] == WHITESPACE || line[i] == TAB) //Skip Spaces or Tabs at the beginning of this line
        {
            i++;
        }
        if(line[i] == '\n') // Skip Blank lines
        {
            continue;
        }
        if(line[i] == '#') //The comments lines begin with a #
        {
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
                for(i=6;line[i]!='\n'&&line[i]!=-1;i++)
                {

                    if(line[i]<='9'&&line[i]>='0')
                    {
                        if (start==1&&k==0)
                        {
                            b=atoi(s);
                            memset(s, 0, sizeof(s));
                        }
                        else if (start==2&&k==0)
                        {
                            c=atoi(s);
                            memset(s, 0, sizeof(s));
                            if (b>=1&&c>=1)
                            {
                                sequence[b-1][c-1]=1;
                            }
                            //printf("b=%d,c=%d\n",b,c);
                        }
                        s[k]=line[i];
                        for(;line[i+1]<='9'&&line[i+1]>='0';)
                        {
                            i++;
                            k++;
                            s[k]=line[i];
                        }
                        if (line[i-k-1]=='r')
                        {
                            start=1;
                        }
                        else if(line[i+1]=='\n')
                        {
                            c=atoi(s);
                            memset(s, 0, sizeof(s));
                            if (b>=1&&c>=1)
                            {
                                sequence[b-1][c-1]=1;
                            }
                            //printf("b=%d,c=%d\n",b,c);
                            continue;
                        }
                        else if(line[i+1]==EOF)
                        {
                            c=atoi(s);
                            memset(s, 0, sizeof(s));
                            if (b>=1&&c>=1)
                            {
                                sequence[b-1][c-1]=1;
                            }
                            //printf("b=%d,c=%d\n",b,c);
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            start=2;
                        }
                        //k++;

                    }
                    else if (start==1 || start==2 )
                    {
                        k=0;
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

My question is that the program always cannot read well the last line and I think maybe it's because of EOF. Does anyone know solution?

Comment: Is there a newline at the end of the `router6` line?

Comment: If the `router6` line does _not_ have a newline at the end, the `for` loop condition is wrong. Change `for (i = 6; line[i] != '\n' && line[i] != -1; i++)` into `for (i = 6; line[i] != '\n' && line[i] != 0; i++)` Comparing anything in `line` against `EOF` is wrong. `EOF` is the end-of-file return value from `fgetc`. It has nothing to do with a buffer returned by `fgets`. Perhaps you want: `line[i + 1] == EOF` --> `line[i + 1] == 0`

Comment: If we add a new line with "####", the code can well work but I try to find a way to avoid it.@Fiddling Bits

Comment: fantastic idea.It can fonction right now.I have another question, is there any way to allow the space after each line? I add a space after "16" at the last line and it cannot detect 16.@Craig Estey